# Connect to Azure SQL database using SSMS via AAD MFA when account is guest of another directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have a problem when connecting to an Azure SQL Database using SSMS under this scenario:

- Have a work laptop connected to work domain via VPN
- The database is in a different Azure tenant (tenant B) to my work Azure tenant
  (tenant A).
- My work account is set up via AAD in the work Azure tenant (A)
  and is a guest account in other tenant (B)
- Have the latest version of SSMS
- Granted user access to the Azure SQL database
- I connect via SSMS using the Azure Active Directory - Universal
  with MFA option
- Note all default options are set and have also tried setting the database

I know the database access has been correctly set up as **I have successfully been able to connect in the above scenario when I use Azure Data Studio instead of SSMS**, but only because I have the option to change "Azure AD tenant" property from "Tenant A" to "Default Directory".

I have been able to connect OK when using SSMS with my personal computer using the same account / method, except it is not using a work account and is not connected to the work domain.

Seems like my issue is that I cannot change the "Azure AD tenant" property in SSMS and it is using the tenant associated with my account.  I have also tested with a number of different people and they have the same issue.  **I have also set the default Azure directory to tenant B in the Azure portal.**

Does anyone have any suggestion how I can get this to work in SSMS?

[Azure Data Studio connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK8Sr.jpg)

Thanks Tony

Comment: According to my understanding, the sql database is in the tenant B and the user is tenant  A. And you add user A to tenant B as a guest user and set user A as SQL database AD user. Now you want to know how to connect Azure SQL database via ssms with user A. Right? If so, you can directly connect SQL with the user and do not need to set the domain name. Because with SSMS 18.x or later, it will automatically recognize domain : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-mfa-ssms-overview#azure-ad-domain-name-or-tenant-id-parameter

Comment: @JimXu Hi Jim, yes your understanding is correct & I saw this link and worked through it, and I am using v18.5.1.  In my scenario listed above, I think SSMS is somehow authenticating with tenant A on the work laptop... but when I set the additional tenant setting in Azure Data Studio, it is authenticating to tenant B.

Comment: As far as I knew, when we connect SQL via SSMS with MFA, it is authenticating to tenant B which has the sql server.  the tool will get Azure AD access token and send the access token to the SQL server then SQL sever will analyze token to check if the user is in the tenant and the database has the user.

Comment: @JimXu Thanks Jim.  There could be things different between our remote laptop connection and yours.  Maybe VPN, not sure.  I have tested with 4 different users and the same result.  I have posted an answer as a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am answering my own question.

I have a work-around which involves:

1. Create a connection in Azure Data Studio and setting the Azure AD Tenant to "default directory"
2. In SSMS, connect to the Database using the Azure Data Studio connection in the Registered Servers pane

Not ideal, but it works.